# Using C++ classes from Go using Swig

Tags: c++, go, swig

I want to use C++ class from Go using swig in Windows7

When I build the project "go build main.go" I am getting following error:

> c:\..\Temp\go-build591352403/swtest.a(swtest_wrap.o): malformed pe file: __cgo_topofstack: invalid symbol binding 105

I am using go 1.3 32bit, gcc 4.8.1 32bit and swig 3.0 in Windows7.
I see same error when I use 64bit Go and GCC in Windows7.

I am able build and run successfully on Ubuntu with 64-bit go and gcc.

Am I missing something in windows?

Here is the file structure and content.

main (folder)

- main.go

  ```
  package main

  import (
    "swtest"
  )

  func main() {
    swtest.NewSwt().Print("Swig test!")
  }
  ```

swtest (folder)

- swtest.cpp

  ```
  #include "swtest.h"

  void Swt::Print(const std::string& s)
  {
      std::cout << s;
      std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- swtest.h

  ```
   #ifndef SWTEST_H
   #define SWTEST_H

   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>

   class Swt
   {
   public:
      void Print(const std::string& s);
   };

   #endif
  ```
- swtest.go

  ```
   package swtest
  ```
- swtest.swigcxx

  ```
  %module swtest
  %include "std_string.i"

  %{
  #include "swtest.h"
  %}

  %include "swtest.h"
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please upgrade to Go 1.5. This problem is solved in Go 1.5.
It was known problem in Windows OS in prior Go versions. Go team has fixed in 1.5.
Please take a look at following thread which will give more information.

[Go with SWIG error in Windows](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/hLc8fHv3ppc)

Comment: whats the reason? any explanation please ? if you dont have anything to explain than please give this type of answer in comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are feeling bold, the pe error on windows is fixed in Go 1.5beta1. Give it a spin! Download [1.5 beta2](https://golang.org/dl/#go1.5beta2)